# Comparing file contents cross platform

Tags: java, unit-testing, file-io

I have a file that has been created on Windows, so it has carriage returns "\r\n".

The file is used in a test, the contents of the file are compared to the contents of a file that is generated during the test. The test passes on Windows because the generated file has the same carriage return.

But the test doesn't pass on Unix/Mac.

It fails because the generated file has linefeeds, ie. only "\n".

Can any one advise how to deal with this?

Edit:
The test is a JUnit (Java) test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up not using a real file, and had the test create the file on the platform at runtime using the system property to get the platforms line terminator.

Comment: this is probably the best solution, as it prevents the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

- You could compare files reading them line-by-line
- You could have two different sample files for unix/windows

Comment: Option 1 is a possibility but it's a low level way of doing it. Option 2, adds overhead in maintaining 2 files and adds complexity to decide which file is required in the test depending on the OS, not ideal really. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: If it is JUnit, the best option would be to update your comparison function/procedure. Unless you are comparing files byte-by-byte, you could use Regular Expression to replace line-separators (both unix and win) to some expected char sequence (e.g., `|n`)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following to avoid reading line by line with

```
String text = FileUtils.readFileAsString(filename)
                       .replaceAll("(\r\n|\r|\n)", "\n");
```

This replaces all new-lines of any type with "\n"